# Sounds Don't Always Load AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I do not know why, but whenever I try to load a sound into my game, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

When it works, the only output is some newgrounds api.

But sometimes, this happens:

```
Error opening URL 'http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/download/700566'
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
    at rotationgame_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at com.newgrounds.components::FlashAdBase/set showBorder()
    at com.newgrounds.components::APIConnector/__setProp_ad_APIConnector_AD_0()
    at com.newgrounds.components::APIConnector/__setProp_handler()
```

I dont know why, but here is my code for all the audio

### Frame 1

```
var bkgmusic:Sound= new Sound();
bkgmusic.load(new URLRequest("http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/download/700566"));
var igmusic:Sound=new Sound();
igmusic.load(new URLRequest("http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/download/651218"));
```

### Frame 2

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
channel=bkgmusic.play();
```

### Frame 3

```
channel.stop();
channel=igmusic.play();
```

### Frame 4

```
channel=bkgmusic.play();
```

I can't give you the code for the API connector (for newgrounds), but if you agree to their API terms of service, you can see for yourself.

The only thing it seems to affect is the audio, I don't know why.
And I have no idea where this is:

```
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
```

This is the link to the game (the output is the API output, so that wont help, this is just to show the problem)
http://www.newgrounds.com/projects/games/1015606/preview

I made a document with all the code in it (for frame 1), here it is:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-jQ7SlQxL7CPL87Vwrl_eEUibgjyVZJ15-Sp4DezHsM/edit?usp=sharing

if anybody needs anything tell me

Comment: Where do you use the API connector in your code?

Comment: The api connector is a symbol. If you want to see what it is and how it works, make a newgrounds account, press "upload your creations", click game, create a new game, at the side click API tools, accept, and then find the AS3 one

Comment: You might get better answers when asking them for support.

Comment: im pretty sure its a problem with the audio, but ill try to do a MySound instead of a sound